# Is there something like an intranet scoped GAC?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Can I achieve the deployment of a .NET assembly into a location such that all dependent programs now use it as long as they reference that locaiton.

If it's not built into the framework, is there another mechanism or a way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I'm lost. Could you give an example?

Comment: say you had two solutions - one for applications and another for libraries.  I'd like it if all i had to do was recompile my libraries and not worry about the applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes *(kind of)* - but you have to set it up yourself.

.Net program can search specified directories **under** the AppDomain base directory. It's called the [Probing Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It's important to note that it must be **under** the directory.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="MySpecialPath"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

So we just put a symbolic link under the applications directory (MySpecialPath) and it would happily use the central directory. Of course since .net always looks in the GAC first - you can't do it for GAC assemblies.

I also used it to get round the old [MS Test AppDomain Issue](http://preetsangha.blogspot.co.nz/2008/06/getting-round-visual-studio-2008-mstest.html) (my blog).

Answer (score 0):

No.

Either deploy it in each of those applications bin directories or the GAC with a particular version number.  The dependent apps should look for that particular version.

Comment: i recently saw something that made me think an assembly could be referenced by URL... but I can't remember the context - anyway that's what made me think maybe it was possible.  Thanks for the answer though.